# Why JTextfield's text value is not changing visually by using a variable?

Tags: java, variables, methods, parameter-passing, jtextfield

I am doing a project to make a board game using JAVA. Now I want when a player wins, the score will be shown in a Jtextfield.So to do this at first I used a method to get the JTextfield from the Player1Graphics Class in the Declarewin method() that is in the GamePlan class.But this showed me a NullPointerException.

So I thought another way.As I can't make object of the GameGui Class to any other class because it will create infinite loop. So I have used another class named Player class and created a variable "SName" which will take the value from the "score" variable that is in the decarewin() method.Then I used an updatetextfied() method in Player1Graphics class that is an inner Class of GameGui Class and set the "SName" variable on it.Now in runtime all the variable is working well they are passing the value as expected and the JTextfield text value is also updating but visual of JTextfield is not updating.It's not changing from 0 to 1 or 1 to 2.

I am givin the code below.............

This are the codes from GameGui Class........

```
public class GameGui extends JFrame{


    GameGui(){

    super("Board");
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(700,800);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setResizable(false);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    this.setContentPane(main_panel);
    main_panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    main_panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    resourcer();

}


resourcer(){


//players
    JPanel playersroom = new JPanel();

    //playersroom.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
    playersroom.setBackground(Color.white);
    playersroom.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    JPanel player1room = new JPanel();
    player1room.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    //player1room.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 0, 0, 1, Color.BLACK));
    player1room.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350,300));
    player1room.add(new Player1graphics(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    playersroom.add(player1room,BorderLayout.WEST);


    arena.add(playersroom,BorderLayout.CENTER);




    main_panel.add(arena,BorderLayout.SOUTH);






}
```

This is the player1Graphics Class that holds the JTextfield and it is the Inner Class of GameGui Class.

```
public class Player1graphics extends JPanel{
    private String newname;
     JLabel name = new JLabel("PLAYER 1",SwingConstants.CENTER);
    JButton setname = new JButton("CN");
    GamePlan g = new GamePlan();
    JButton token = new JButton("POISON");

    JTextField showscore = new JTextField(20); //this is the JTextfield


    Player1graphics(){
        //repaint();
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(new Color(255,220,154));


        //setname code & name code
        //JButton setname = new JButton("CN");

        setname.setBounds(160, 40, 30, 20);
        setname.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1, true));
        setname.setToolTipText("Change the name");




        name.setBounds(132, 70, 80, 30);
        name.setOpaque(true);
        name.setBackground(new Color(102,140,185));
        name.setForeground(new Color(202,208,215));
        name.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));




    setname.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public  void  actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                 newname = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"ENTER YOUR NAME");
                if (newname==null){
                name.setText("PLAYER 1");
                }else{
                    t1=1;
                name.setText(newname);

                getfirstplayername(newname);
                }

            }
        });


        //token button code
        //JButton token = new JButton("POISON");
        token.setBackground(new Color(233,249,254));


        token.setBounds(132, 110, 80, 30);
        token.setToolTipText("token can be used only one time");
        ActionClass ac = new ActionClass();
        ac.getfirstplayerpoisonbutton(token);
        token.addActionListener(ac);


        //won and showin textfieldcode
        JLabel won = new JLabel("Won",SwingConstants.CENTER);
        won.setBorder( BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(102,140,185), 2, true));
        won.setBounds(132, 150, 50, 30);
        won.setBackground(new Color(102,140,185));
        won.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

//JTextfield codes
        //JTextField showwin = new JTextField();
        //GamePlan gm = new GamePlan();

        Player player = new Player();
        showscore.setBounds(185, 150, 30, 30);

        showscore.setEditable(false);

        //showwin.setOpaque(true);
        //showwin.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        //showwin.setText(player.sname);
        updatetextfield(player.sname);

        this.add(name);
        this.add(setname);
        this.add(token);
        this.add(won);
        this.add(showscore);
        repaint();

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D myg = (Graphics2D) g;
        myg.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        myg.setColor(new Color(163,193,231));
        myg.fillOval(25, 10, 300, 200);


    }


    public void updatetextfield(String s){



        showscore.setText(s);
        showscore.repaint();

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, showwin.getText());
    }



}
```

This is the JTextfield code.................

```
    JTextField showscore = new JTextField(20);
    Player player = new Player();

        showscore.setBounds(185, 150, 30, 30);

        showscore.setEditable(false);
        updatetextfield(player.sname);
```

This is the updatetextfield method code..........

```
public void updatetextfield(String s){



        showscore.setText(s);
        showscore.repaint();

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, showscore.getText());
    }
```

This is the variable that I created in the player class..........

```
public class Player{

 String sname =  Integer.toString(GamePlan.score);


}
```

This is the declarewin method where the score variable updates and it is in another class named GamePlan Class.

```
public class GamePlan{

static int score=0;  


public void declarewin(){

    score++;  //score variable updating

    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
            bbutton[i][j].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, score);
    Player pl = new Player();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pl.sname);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU have won the   game");
}
```

I have used a lot of JOption to see if the variables are passing the value or not and also I used the gettext() method to see if the value of JTextfield is changing or not.And yes all the value is changing but only the visual of Textfield is not changing. Though in inside JTextfield text value is 1 or 2 but it shows 0 in the GUI.IT never changes................

I have spent a couple of hours to solve this but I couldn't.It's just making me mad.

Will anyone please help to get me out of this mess............. :| :|

Comment: Have you added Player1graphics panel to main windows?, put Main Frame code

Comment: do you ever call the `updatetextfield` method apart from in the initialization code?

Comment: I have added the main frame code............@Michele Lacorte

Comment: I am calling the updatetextfield() method in the Player1GraphicsClass Constructor...............@Subler

Comment: if you only call it in the constructor, it will never update it after starting up the game, hence why it stays at 0 ?

Comment: Then where I should call it...............? :/........Actually the value of JTextfield text is changing in inside but it's not showing in the gui.............:|...........@Subler

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the textfield everytime you update the value of the player.sname varible.

Right now you create a copy of the score and save it in the textfield. 
You need to call the updatetextfield function again with the new value.

see this example:

```
public class GamePlan{

    static int score=0;  

    //First new line
    GameGui referenceToGui //Get this reference somethere

    public void declarewin(){

        score++;  //score variable updating
        //Second new line
        referenceToGui.updateTextField(""+score); 

        for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<20;j++){
                bbutton[i][j].setEnabled(false);
            }
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, score);
        Player pl = new Player();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, pl.sname);

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "YOU have won the   game");
    }
```

Comment: I have done this as you showed.........but as updatetextfield() method is in the player1graphics class and that is the innerclass of GameGUi class.So I am unable to use the updatetextfield() method directly using the GameGUi reference.So I used chain command like this 
// code
'GameGui reference;
reference.pl1.updatetextfield("" + score);  //pl1 is the object of player1graphics class '

But compiler showing me the null pointer exception.......@Denis.......:/